# Install ifort on Ubuntu 20

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I am trying to install the ifort compiler on Ubuntu20. I downloaded the installation file from the site: [intel](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/oneapi-standalone-components.html#fortran)

[image]

This is a file with the extension .sh, which I made executable:

```
  Downloads$ chmod +x l_fortran-compiler_p_2021.1.2.62_offline.sh
  Downloads$ ./l_fortran-compiler_p_2021.1.2.62_offline.sh
```

This opened the software installer:

[image]
[image]

However, I cannot use the ifort compiler. Example:

```
  ifort -o name name.for
```

It gives the following message:

```
  Command 'ifort' not found, did you mean:

    command 'fort' from deb fort-validator (1.2.0-1)
    command 'isort' from deb isort (4.3.4+ds1-2)

  Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

I need to install the intel ifort compiler because the executable is faster if I compile with the -fast option.

Comment: Is the installed ifort command in your path?

Comment: @francescalus The installation was apparently done in the directory "../intel/oneapi/" If I compile into this directory I get the same message. Could you please explain in a little more detail if I need to do something additional?

Comment: Have you followed all required steps in [the documentation](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/get-started-with-intel-oneapi-base-linux/top/before-you-begin.html)?

Comment: You must load the environment using the script provided. I am sure we have existing duplicates.

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/get-started-with-intel-oneapi-base-linux/top/before-you-begin.html) says how to set the environment:

```
For root or sudo installations:

. /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh

For normal user installations:

. ~/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh
```

You can put these into your bash profile or bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to "activate" the intel compilers with:

```
source /opt//oneapi/setvars.sh
```

Comment: How does this differ from the older answer?

Comment: @Neinstein, neither the other answer nor the documentation ask for `./script.sh`, but `. script.sh` which is something completely different (and `. script.sh` being the same in Bash as `source script.sh`).

Answer (score 0):

there is also a file named **modulefiles-setup.sh** with **setvars.sh** file ,in the same folder(/intel/oneapi/) . you need to activate both files with command(source file.sh) to see ifort and icc commands.
use this commands:

```
 source intel/oneapi/setvars.sh 

 source intel/oneapi/modulefiles-setup.sh

 source .bashrc
```